# AutoLayoutでUILabelのサイズを計算してるのはMainThread内でしょうか

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, autolayout

AutoLayoutはUILabelのサイズを計算する時にMainThreadで行っていますか？その場合、多くの書き換えが起こるとMainThreadがロックされるのではと考えています。

また、その場合、AutoLayoutを使ったまま回避する方法はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

MainThreadで処理が行われると考えていますが、一般的なiOSアプリの構成ではロックは発生しないと思います(UILabelを10000個配置するなどをしない限り)